# Extract image filename with extension - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

i see many options on the internet, but it is not what I want. 
I want to get the image name, but with extension with JS.
Even if the path to the image file and image is something like:

> folder/folder1/fol.der/my.image.jpg

The result must be:

> my.image.jpg

Comment: _"I want to get the image name"_ How is image file retrieved ? What have you tried ?

Comment: I want to remove path to the image, but not the image + extension. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into an array and get the last item.

```
var filePath = "folder/folder/fol.der/my.image.jpg";
var pathArray = filePath.split("/");
var fileName = pathArray[pathArray.length-1]; // returns my.image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the solution:

```
var img = "/path1/pa.th2/dfgdfgdfg.ghfgh.jpg"
var basename = img.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace(/.*\//, '');
```

Result:

> dfgdfgdfg.ghfgh.jpg

If this can help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably more complex than required:

```
var dir = "folder/folder1/fol.der/my.image.jpg";

var getFileName = function(dir){
  return dir.replace(/[\w\.\/]+(?=\/)\/([\w/.]+)/g, "$1");
}

getFileName(dir);
```

The function getFileName takes a directory string and returns a filename string. It does a regex match against any number of directories, matches everything after the last matched directory, replaces the dir string with the matched group, and returns it.

Comment: Reviewer here! Can you provide a little context explaining what your answer does rather than simply providing a block of code? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely! Edited with an explanation.